# If the annual inflation rate is 3.2%, how can I calculate the daily inflation rate??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that I cannot just take 3.2% and divide by 365.  Sorry I'm a math noob...

Comment: Is the daily rate taken to be constant?

Comment: No you have to take the 365th root. The (average) daily inflation is $(1+0.032)^{1/365}-1=0.00863\%$ For more explanation see the answer of Donald (Mew).

Comment: Hey calculus! Ok, let's supposed that there is 252 days a year (that is trading days), can you help do the math for me and see how much percentage a day inflation goes up by? Thanks in advance, I will do mine too so we can double check the result.

Comment: The inflation rate per day is equal, because the trading are spread over the whole year. The inflation rate does not depend on the number of days of trading.

Comment: Haha, that's smart.  But I only got 252 days of data a year and I will have to count on those datas.  I got an answer of 1.00012500252272  can you double check for me?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha confirms your computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.032%5E(1%2F252)). If you assume that there is no inflation happening on non-trading days, then such an average inflation on trading days might make sense. Sounds implausible to me, though. The world doesn't stand still just because the stock markets are closed, and the things happening on those days will likely be reflected in the opening prices on the next trading day. So I'd rather assume a regular year (of $365.2425$ days if you want an average year, or of the known number of days for a specific year).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be the daily inflation rate.

Assuming a constant daily inflation rate, then $(1+x)^{365} = 1 + 0.032$

Therefore,

$(1+x) = 1.032^{1/365} = 1.0000863$

Therefore $x = 0.0000863 = 0.00863\%$

Therefore the daily inflation rate is $0.00863\%$.

Comment: * if daily rate is constant

Comment: @gowrath I would say average daily rate.

Comment: Isn't this also assuming there are 365 days in the year? :)

Comment: Let's assume that there is 252 days in a year, What would the daily inflation rate be?  I say 252 days because there are 252 days when the stock market is open.

Comment: @ChoongJing Replace the 365 in the answer with 252 and you'll get your answer :)

Comment: @callculus Agreed. I think in financial maths, as you said, there is not such thing as a daily rate. It is actually an average (geometric mean?) of the yearly one.

Comment: @gowrath I did that and I got the answer of 1.000125003, can you double check for me?  The accuracy is very import for this...

Comment: @ChoongJing SE is not a place to get people to double check your calculations. See answer below.

Comment: @ChoongJing The INFLATION RATE is independent from the number of trading rates The average inflation rate (per day) is always $ i_d=(1+i)^{1/365}-1$ (assuming 365 days). Maybe you mean something different like daily growth rate of an stock exchange index.

Comment: @gowrath That is indeed the geometric mean.

Comment: As far as my limited financial knowledge goes, @callculus is technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

Let the daily rate be $r$, $y$ the yearly rate, and $d$ the number of trading in a year. Then you have:

$$
\begin{align}
(1+r)^d &= (1+y) \\
 1+r &= (1+y)^{\frac{1}{d}}  \\
 1+r &= (1+y)^{\frac{1}{d}} \\
 r & =  (1+y)^{\frac{1}{d}} -1\\ 
\end{align}
$$

In your case, $r = (1+0.032)^{\frac{1}{252}} - 1 = 0.0001250025227173$